# Animate gameobject using unity animation with constant speed

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm animating a object in my scene using the built in gameobject record feature. I add keyframes each 10 second and move my gameobject. Problem is I want the speed to be constant. But since distance between each keyframe is different speed will change.

Is there a automated feature to move keyframes so taht I get constant speed?

Comment: Your question reads a little confusing as the animation is a fixed speed, therefore if your character is positioned every 10s it will always play a the same speed, if however you are moving say 1m in 10s in the first section and 10m in the next 10s, then yes your character will have different speeds, I  dont believe there is an automated tool to work this out, other than, faff about with your keyframes after you make them till it seems the same speed or calculate its velocity in code for each section and have that tell you how to adjust the keyframes

Comment: I wrote a little script that takes the normal vector between two keyframes and corrects the keyframe delta time so that I can constant speed.